# Value not coming into the textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services

I have `webservice` code which is been called on `Pagemethod` from javascript to fill the textbox value, but it is not getting filled.

Here is my `Webservice` code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetStatus(string statuschk)
{
    List<string> status = new List<string>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(statuschk))
    {
        DataTable Dtgridstatus = new DataTable();
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());

        con.Open();
        string strSql = "Select FLAT_NO ||'~'|| FLAT_STATUS STATUS from xxacl_pn_flat_det_v where FLAT_ID = '" + statuschk + "'";
        OracleDataAdapter odaptunit = new OracleDataAdapter(strSql, con);

        odaptunit.Fill(Dtgridstatus);
        for (int i = 0; i < Dtgridstatus.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            status.Add(Dtgridstatus.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    return status;
}
```

It returns me `Flat_Id` and I use this `webservice` in javascript to fill the textbox like below:

```
 function Funchangestatus() {
        PageMethods.GetStatus(document.getElementById('ddlUnit').value, onstatuschange);
    }
    function onstatuschange(status) {
        strstatus = status.split('~');
        document.getElementById("txtStatus").value = strstatus[0];
    }
```

but it is not getting filled.

Comment: your status variable is an array, you should probably split on ~ after getting the first element out.

Comment: @JohnBoker: can you tell me how to split that ??

Comment: You dont really split arrays you access indices, so if you wanted the first value in the array to split you would do something like strstatus = status[0].split('~');

Comment: what @Bearcat9425 said.

Comment: Not sure also if its coming back as parsed Json or not so you might need to parse it as json first to get it into a Json array then access it like I mentioned.

Comment: @Bearcat9425: tried like this, but not working `function onstatuschange(status) {
                strstatus = status[0].split('~');
                document.getElementById("txtStatus").value = strstatus[0];
            }`

Comment: @JohnBoker: tried that way, still not working. My query gives me output as `23111~UNBOOKED`

Comment: are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: @JohnBoker: No, not any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
function onstatuschange(status) {
        strstatus = status[0].split('~');
        document.getElementById("txtStatus").value = strstatus[0];
    }
```

Comment: checked in console, getting error as `Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Comment: document.getElementById("txtStatus") is returning null, are you sure you have an element on the page with id="txtStatus" and it's not a mangled asp.net id?

Comment: yes, i have an id like this:- `<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtstatus" style="width: auto" />`

Comment: that line has the id as all lower case, case matters.

Comment: S is capitalized in status of your ID in the GetElementById call you need to make that lower

Comment: yes, that was the issue, I m MAD. didn't caught that. anyways thanks to both for pointing out this

Comment: no problem, an easy thing to miss :) thanks for the rep.